# How to create a vector function in sympy?

Tags: python, sympy

I am looking for a way in SymPy to create a function  (u,v) -> (x,y,z) converting two elements to three and then take a derivative from a resulting vector. It would look like this in Sage:

```
u = var('u')
v = var('v')
x = (2 + sin(u) *sin(v)) *sin(3*v/2) 
y = cos(u) *sin(v) + 2 *v/pi - 2 
z = (2 + sin(u) *sin(v)) *cos(3*v/2)
r(u, v) = [x, y, z]
e1 = derivative(r, u)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

SymPy has a [Vector module](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/vector/index.html) which is oriented toward doing calculus in various coordinate systems. But if you don't need to do coordinate transformations, it is more straightforward to represent a vector as a one-column matrix `Matrix([x, y, z])`, like so:

```
from sympy import *
var('u v')
x = (2 + sin(u) *sin(v)) *sin(3*v/2) 
y = cos(u) *sin(v) + 2 *v/pi - 2 
z = (2 + sin(u) *sin(v)) *cos(3*v/2)
   # everything so far was as in your code 
r = Matrix([x, y, z])
e1 = r.diff(u)
pprint(e1)    # "pretty" print
```

Output (assuming no LaTeX processing):

```
⎡          ⎛3⋅v⎞       ⎤
⎢sin(v)⋅sin⎜───⎟⋅cos(u)⎥
⎢          ⎝ 2 ⎠       ⎥
⎢                      ⎥
⎢    -sin(u)⋅sin(v)    ⎥
⎢                      ⎥
⎢                 ⎛3⋅v⎞⎥
⎢sin(v)⋅cos(u)⋅cos⎜───⎟⎥
⎣                 ⎝ 2 ⎠⎦
```

Comment: I want to do coordinate transformations. How does it work then?