# How to create a vector function in sympy with actual vectors, that can be transformed between coordinate systems?

Tags: python, sympy, symbolic-math

I saw this [answer][1]
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46993819/how-to-create-a-vector-function-in-sympy
which uses `Matrix()` as a workaround.

I need to transform my input and output vector from one coordinate system to another (and back). How are vector functions done in that case? My function is simple:

```
def B_el(r_vec):
    r1 = r_vec.i
    r2 = r_vec.j
    u = sin(r1)+cos(r2)
    v = -cos(r1)+sin(r2)
    return Matrix([u, v, 0])
```

Comment: @hpaulj I did that. The best I found was https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/physics/vector/api/classes.html#vector, but that does not seem to do what I want. But then I lack sympy experience. Can you be more verbose, please?

Comment: Yes, I can. What do I look for? If you have something specific in mind, can you say what it is, @hpaulj?

Comment: Andreas, you might also try the Sympy forum on Google groups: https://groups.google.com/g/sympy

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you use the coordinate systems (csys in the text below) described in "vector"
https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/vector/coordsys.html

that's the best solution I've found so far.

```
from sympy import symbols
from sympy.vector import CoordSys3D, express

grd = CoordSys3D('grd')
# this declares the existence of a csys, named grd

alpha, X, Y, Z = symbols('alpha, X, Y, Z')

slo = grd.orient_new_axis('slo', alpha, grd.k, location=2*grd.j)
# This creates a new csys named slo, rotated with an angle alpha around 
# the axis k of grd (=grd.k), and locates it at 2 on the axis j of grd
# (x y z are replaced by i j k)

V = X*slo.i + Y*slo.j + Z*slo.k
# this defines a vector V with coordinates (X, Y, Z), in the csys slo.

display(V)
display(express(V, slo))
display(express(V, grd))
# this will display the coordinates of the vector V, and then express its coordinates
# in the csys slo & grd.
```